# places.sqlite buggy? seems to behave abnormally. How to get $LAST_VISITED_URL?

Tags: bash, firefox, sqlite

I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com).

Here is my `last-url.sh`

```bash
    #!/bin/bash
    
    rm  -rf /tmp/db.sqlite 
    cp ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default-esr/places.sqlite /tmp/db.sqlite ;
    LAST_URL=`sqlite3 /tmp/db.sqlite "select url from moz_places order by last_visit_date desc limit 1;"`;

    echo $LAST_URL
```

My script keeps giving me an example of a [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) URL instead of the [youtube.com](https://youtube.com) one, even if I reload the page.

Where is the issue hiding?

I have only one `xxxxxx.default-esr` profile.

Screenshot:
[firefox history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcl9S.png)
[sqlite database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzVXK.png)

Testing Examples: the "google test" is a brand new visited URL, and the others were refreshed pages

Now I ask myself how Firefox creates the history tab (it reflects the real history). Is it using which file or which SQL request on places? SQLite?

Comment: I've edited your post, and removed the foul language.  Please remember this is a public forum with thousands, if not millions of daily visitors

Comment: @eyoung100 Don't take it bad, and i'm not native english but didn't you just change the meaning of the phrase by changing "for example" by "an exemple of" ? I give those two url as exemples, and were imaginated... But this is not a grammar forum. take it easy. Thanks for the rest of editing anyway. Love

Comment: I don't think I changed the meaning.  I understand you're not a native speaker.  I help plenty of non-native speakers here.  In regards to your question I believe you need to adjust your SQL query to either  return the greatest `id` or change the limit to `0`.  That database looks [0 based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)

Comment: @eyoung100 I changing limit to `0` return empty value and sorting by  `id` won't work with refreshed pages, but at least that work for new visited ones.

Comment: What happens if you change the limit to 0 and run the script with the BROWSER CLOSED? I believe the last visited page isn't updated/added to the database until 1.) a new page is visited, or 2.) The browser is closed and the last page is added.  For refreshed pages, use `visit_count`

Comment: @eyoung100 Still got empty value with `0` with firefox closed.`visited_count` can't help me i think, it just give me the number of time the page has been refreshed. It can't give me use-full info about history (or i don't get it).

Comment: See my answer below.  Let me know if the new query works, or for any syntax errors.  I wrote the query from a Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

### Script Modification

```bash
 #!/bin/bash
    
    rm  -rf /tmp/db.sqlite 
    cp ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default-esr/places.sqlite /tmp/db.sqlite ;
    ORIG_QUERY=`select url from moz_places order by last_visit_date desc limit 1;`
    NEW_QUERY=`SELECT url FROM moz_places WHERE visited_count >=1 GROUP BY last_visit_date DESC ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
    LAST_URL=`sqlite3 /tmp/db.sqlite ${QUERY}`;
    TEST_URL=`sqlite3 /tmp/db.sqlite ${NEW_QUERY};`

    #echo $LAST_URL
    echo $TEST_URL
```

### Explanation

The OP ensured that the database wasn't 0 based, per their comments below the question.  My SQL is a bit rusty, but the query stored in `${NEW_QUERY}` should return "The first row URL whether new(`visit_count=1`) or refreshed(`visit_count > 1`) with the `id`s from largest to smallest grouped by date".  In other words:

*If you visited 1,000 pages today and 500 yesterday, and didn't have a LIMIT, you should see 1,000 pages listed under today's date, and 500 under yesterday's, with the big ID's at the top.*  Having the LIMIT set should return the URL with the highest `id` for the `last_visited` date including any page refreshes.

Comment: I got a syntax error ```Error: in prepare, near "desc": syntax error```

Comment: Anyway, i think we are trying to access a data that is NOT present in the database yet. See below

Answer (score 0):

A beginning of answer from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1441694) thanks to jscher2000, but not a solution yet

> Some history may be cached in memory, but the Library window shows a lot of entries, so presumably it is going to disk for that information. The SQLite engine is constructing that from the places.sqlite file and from its journaling files, so it has a more complete view than you do simply operating on the one file.

So maybe the solution can come from a tool like [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) trying to parse the places.sqlite.wal.
I will try that.

And as @jscher2000 says

> Firefox writes -wal and -shm files.
> ... I'm puzzled why sqlite3 doesn't handle it automatically.
> ... https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html